# my if statement isn't working properly? can't get to the elif statement - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
switch = True
players = []
while True:
    user_adding = input("Would you like to add?  yes or no ")
    user_adding = user_adding.title()
    if user_adding.lower() == "yes":
        player_name = input("who do you want on the list? ")
        players.append(player_name)
        number_of_players = len(players)
    elif user_adding.lower() == "no":
        player_1 = players[0]
        print(player_1)
        print(f"There are {number_of_players}")
        switch = False
```

Can't get to the elif statement here and i am not sure why...what could it be..

Comment: What are you typing at the input prompt?

Comment: tried no, No both

Comment: If you enter "no" during your first run you'll get `IndexError: list index out of range` because `players[0]` doesn't exist. How do you run your program that you don't see the error?

Comment: What makes you think you aren't reaching the `elif` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enter "no" to get to the `elif`, but you need to have done `yes` first or the code will raise an exception at `players[0]`:

```
Would you like to add?  yes or no yes
who do you want on the list? Bob
Would you like to add?  yes or no no
Bob
There are 1
```

Some notes on this code: the `switch` value is never used, and there's no reason to `title()` case `user_adding` if you're going to `lower()` it later.

Here's a slightly simpler version that will break the loop after you say "no", and won't crash if 0 players are entered:

```
players = []
while True:
    user_adding = input("Would you like to add?  yes or no ")
    if user_adding.lower() == "yes":
        player_name = input("who do you want on the list? ")
        players.append(player_name)
    elif user_adding.lower() == "no":
        print(" ".join(players))
        print(f"There are {len(players)}")
        break
    else:
        print(f"I don't know what '{user_adding}' means!")
```

Comment: `Would you like to add a player to the team? (Yes/No): yes
Enter the name of the player to add to the team: Bob
['Bob']
1
Would you like to add a player to the team? (Yes/No): no
Would you like to add a player to the team? (Yes/No): `

Comment: just keeps going over and over again without hitting the elif

Comment: You aren't running the same version of the code that you pasted in here; the `input` prompt text is different.  I assume something else is different too...?

Answer (score 0):

One mistake i saw is that the number_of_players is not accessible in elif statement unless it goes first through if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you are trying to input `no` at the first time, `players` is empty and it will cause an `Indexerror` 

Try :

```
players = []
while True:
    user_adding = input("Would you like to add?  yes or no ")
    user_adding = user_adding.title()
    if user_adding.lower() == "yes":
        player_name = input("who do you want on the list? ")
        players.append(player_name)
        number_of_players = len(players)
    elif user_adding.lower() == "no":
        if len(players) :
            player_1 = players[0]
            print(player_1)
            print(f"There are {number_of_players}")
            switch = False
        else:
            print("No Players")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you aren't entering the `elif`. The problem is that your loop doesn't examine the value of `switch` that the `elif` sets to `False`. You want `while switch:`, not `while True:`.